# CSS - a tag with space in content but possible to href

Tags: html, css

is possible to make content of `<a href="">bla</a>` empty (just space `<a href=""></a>`) with CSS and have an empty a object possible to click on it? If yes, how can I achieve this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
.link {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#">bla</a>
```

Comment: Thats maybe what I am looking for, what about if I want to be that a tag blank, but its not now, i need to make content black with css, but also need to be clickable, its possible to have that tag with invisible text, but still clickable?

Comment: You can also leave the <a> tag blank, it will still work the same way.

Comment: I understand you, but in my case its filled with text and Its not the best to hide the text with javascript, and I thought if its not possible using css

Comment: I used font-size: 0; to hide the text without using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Don't put anything in between the opening and closing anchor tag.  Give the anchor tag a class name.  Then if you give it a height and width along with making the element either `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` you will have a blank spot that is clickable.  You can also apply a background-color or whatever your heart desires.

```css
.blank-link {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: red; //if you desire a background-color
  }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="blank-link"></a>
```

Changing the display to `block` or `inline-block` is really important because anchor tags default to `display: inline;` . When inline, your height and width won't do anything.

*edit* After seeing the other answer I realize now that you have text that you want to hide. `font-size: 0` will work. You can also use `color: transparent;` or even `opacity: 0;` if you don't have a color you want visible on the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          .try-to-hde { 
             display: none;
           }
           a.show-blan-space { 
             display: inline-block;
             background: blue;
             width: 50px;
             height: 50px;
           }
         </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <a class="show-blan-space" href=""><span class="try-to-hde">bla</span></a>
         </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but my text is not wrapped in this span with class